# Querying graph structured data in couchbase

Tags: graph, mapreduce, couchdb, couchbase

Given some couchbase documents representing a graph, for example:

```
{ id: 1, name: "Node 1", type: "node" }
{ id: 2, name: "Node 2", type: "node" }
{ id: 3, name: "Node 3", type: "node" }
{ from_node: 1, to_node: 2, type: "edge" }
{ from_node: 1, to_node: 3, type: "edge" }
```

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to find the names of the nodes connected to node with id 1?

Something like:

```
[ "Node 2", "Node 3" ]
```

Can this be done with views alone (if so, please can you provide some example code)?

Or does it need to be done in the application layer? If so could we modify our data model to make it easier?

I appreciate that there are dedicated graph databases out there specialised for this purpose, but the specifics of our application data mean that these are not entirely suitable and this example has been simplified.

Comment: Using a view would work for your simple example if it were keyed off of the `from_node`. However, I'm guessing you'll have a deeper structure? If so, this isn't something CouchDB is particularly good/efficient at doing within the DB. Views only operate on one doc at a time, and List functions operate on ALL documents (by default, fewer with a filtering query). Many NoSQL DBs have this same issue and some find that materializing the paths is the best option.

Comment: If edges are used only to show connection between two nodes, I think it would be easier not to use them at all. Just store connected nodes in node: `{ id: 1, name: "Node 1", type: "node", connected: [2, 3] }`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a simple way to do that in views, as you probably know, the views in Couchbase are executed during the "set/update" of the document and used to create an index. Views are "indexers".

You cannot read/navigate to another document from the document you are currently indexing so it is not possible to navigate into your graph.

So you will have to do a part of it into your application, you can also look into collated views that may help you to structure a little the document. ( http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.fr/2013/02/introduction-to-collated-views-with.html )